# Update a cell value with Macro VBA

Tags: vba

I want to be able to create a button function macro to update stock values based upon one cell that contains the new value and another that identifies the physical cell address.

Very new to VBA and only have a basic understanding

I have tried the below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range

rng = Range(Range("m2").Value2).Select

Set rng.Value = Range("k2").Value

End Sub
```

So what I want to happen is that when clicking the command button the value in the cell determined by the cell address in M2 is updated to the value in cell K2.

Please help a complete noob trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You `Set` Objects not values:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("m2")

    rng.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("k2").Value

End Sub
```